# How to align a form with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, flexbox

I want to align all my form inputs like the first two inputs (Room, Tourist). (same width)
I used flexbox, but it worked only in the two elements but the others no.
I did the same style of the the first two inputs to the other inputs but it's not working.
the button also included with the flex like the inputs.
every row contains two inputs.
there's my  react code :

```
render() {
    return <div className='device-form'>
      <div className="device-header">Device IMEI: {this.state.device.imei}</div>
      <div className="device-inputs">
        <div>
          <label>Room:</label>
          <select onChange={e => this.setState({ room_id: e.target.value })}>
            <option selected disabled hidden>Room</option>
            {this.state.rooms.map(x => <option value={x.id}>
              {'Room ' + x.room_number + ' Section: ' + x.section + ' / Floor: ' + x.floor}
            </option>)}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Tourist:</label>
          <select onChange={e => this.setState({ tourist_id: e.target.value })}>
            <option selected disabled hidden>Tourist</option>
            {this.state.tourists.map(x => <option value={x.id}>
              {x.first_name + ' ' + x.last_name}
            </option>)}
          </select>
        </div>
        {(this.context.role == 3) ? <div>
          <label htmlFor="imei">IMEI:</label>
          <input defaultValue={this.state.device.imei} id="imei" onInput={e => this.setState({ imei: e.target.value })} />
          <label htmlFor="call_time">Call Time:</label>
          <input defaultValue={this.state.device.call_time} id="call_time" onInput={e => this.setState({ call_time: e.target.value })} />
          <label htmlFor="call_limit">Call Limit:</label>
          <input defaultValue={this.state.device.call_limit} id="call_limit" onInput={e => this.setState({ call_limit: e.target.value })} />
          <label htmlFor="intra_flotte">Intra Flotte:</label>
          <select name="intra_flotte" onInput={e => this.setState({ intra_flotte: e.target.value })}>
            <option selected disabled hidden>Intra Flotte?</option>
            <option value="0">No</option>
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
          </select>
        </div> : null}
      </div>
      <button onClick={this.edit}>Confirm</button>
    </div>;
  }
```

sass file :

```
@import '../../../assets/var';
/*
  Device edit style
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .

*/



.device-form{
  width: 100%;
  // height: 230px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 5px;

}

.device-form .device-header{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: $hellodati-blue;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding:20px;
  color: white;
}

.device-form select{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.device-form input{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  // margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


.device-inputs div{
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 45%;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.device-inputs label{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.device-form button{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: $restaurant-blue;
  color: white;
}
```

this is the current state : 
https://ibb.co/6RmpTzY

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or codepen link?

Comment: The question you ask is not clear, and it's related to styling which is hard to figure by just looking at the code, so it's good to add some screenshots (Sketches) about the current state and desired state that you're looking for

Comment: @Osama_Almaani : I've added a photo link in the bottom

Comment: I saw that, thanks,
Check the answer I posted

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to set the inputs below the [select] elements side by side 2 on each row,

You have all the inputs in one (flex-column) div with width: 45% which will cause all of them to be on one side (left) on top of each other.

to resolve the issue: you only need to add each [label/input] pair in a separate div

Replace the inputs section with this snippet

```
        <>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="imei">IMEI:</label>
            <input
              defaultValue={this.state.device.imei}
              id="imei"
              onInput={e => this.setState({ imei: e.target.value })}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="call_time">Call Time:</label>
            <input
              defaultValue={this.state.device.call_time}
              id="call_time"
              onInput={e => this.setState({ call_time: e.target.value })}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="call_limit">Call Limit:</label>
            <input
                defaultValue={this.state.device.call_limit}
              id="call_limit"
              onInput={e => this.setState({ call_limit: e.target.value })}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="intra_flotte">Intra Flotte:</label>
            <select
              name="intra_flotte"
              onInput={e => this.setState({ intra_flotte: e.target.value })}
            >
              <option selected disabled hidden>
                Intra Flotte?
              </option>
              <option value="0">No</option>
              <option value="1">Yes</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </>
```

Comment: <> is <React.Fragment> if you're using older version of React

Comment: I's not worked : after I added the code look what I have : https://ibb.co/Qc0Dwqg

Comment: it looks like you added the div(s) inside the original div => you need to remove the original div 

{(this.context.role == 3) ? <div> this div (remove it)